# Excel worksheet need increment

Tags: excel, worksheet

I am working on two worksheets to calculate the profit of the products. So what I have to do it take the cell from the main sheet (D3) and take another value and add it to the D3. The following is the formula I got(`=D3+'Profits '!B3+'Profits '!B4+'Profits '!B5+'Profits '!B6)`. the problem is when I scroll down to calculate `D4`, `D5`, `D6` the cell from the `Profits` sheet also increases. I only want the main sheet to increment and remain the same for the other sheet
example

```
=D3+'Profits '!B3+'Profits '!B4+'Profits '!B5+'Profits '!B6
=D4+'Profits '!B3+'Profits '!B4+'Profits '!B5+'Profits '!B6
=D5+'Profits '!B3+'Profits '!B4+'Profits '!B5+'Profits '!B6
```

How can I do that to achieve this formula in excel.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read up on *Relative* and *Absolute* referencing. Precede a row or column address with a $ sign to make it absolute, like $B$6. An absolute reference will not change when copied. Rows and columns can be made absolute independently. $B6 will not change when copied left and right but will change when copied vertically. B$6 won't change when copied up or down but will adjust when copied left and right. $B$6 will be unchanged during any copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precede a row or column address with a $ sign to make it absolute, like $B$6.

An absolute reference will not change when copied to another cell. Rows and columns can be made absolute independently. $B6 will not change when copied left and right but will change when copied vertically. B$6 won't change when copied up or down but will adjust when copied left or right.

$B$6 will be unchanged during any copying.